# How to write properly an accent in a web address?

Tags: hyperref, unicode, urls, accents

I'm trying to write a hyperlink for a DjVu document that includes Latin accent, but for some reason, it only displays properly for the `PDF` one. Specifically, on my list of references (bibliography), I have

```
\hyperref{http://www.something.com/camión/ }{link}.
```

It does not work: neither by replacing the letter `ó` by its Unicode `\unichar{243}` nor by its mathematical accent `\acute{o}`... Furthermore "copy-paste" of the glyph (`ó`) in the LaTEX word processor produces almost the same result, i.e., the above hyperlink in

1. PDF  document, leads to the website

   ```
   http://wwwu.something.com/camión/
   ```
2. DJVU document, leads to the website

   ```
   http://www.something.com/cami"strange symbol"n/
   ```

Please, can you suggest me a way of solving this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the UTF-8 (hex.) representation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{http://www.something.com/cami\%C3\%B3n/ }{link}

\end{document}
```

A site with a table to look up characters: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

As **Heiko Oberdiek** mentions in his comment, the browser might help to get the correct encoded URL: you can copy&paste from the address bar or use the "Copy Link Address" facility.

Comment: The browser might help to get the correct encoded URL: Copy&page from the address bar or 'copy link location'.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thank you. I've added these options to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to have the esoteric url encoding with **Python 3**.

```
import urllib.parse

print(
    urllib.parse.quote(
        "http://www.something.com/camión/", 
        safe = "/:"
    ).replace('%','\%')
)
```

This will give you.

```
http://www.something.com/cami\%C3\%B3n/
```

Comment: Gonzalo Medina: It happens, that it works well for both situations, in PDF and DjVu viewers.

Answer (score 0):

adding the following packages worked for me:

```
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[]{hyperref}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
 \usepackage{lmodern}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Attention here!
\usepackage[]{hyperref} %Attention here!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Attention here!
\usepackage{lmodern} %Attention here!

\title{Accents}
\author{#CLoezaOficial}
\date{November 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Accents}
\url{https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo:Planos_anatómicos.svg} %Attention here!

\end{document}
```

[image]