# hyperref won't work with accented characters

Tags: hyperref, accents

I have the following issue with hyperref and accented characters that I can't work out:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{http://epfl.academia.edu/AlejandroAragón}{my academic profile}

\href{http://epfl.academia.edu/AlejandroArag\'{o}n}{my academic profile}

\href{http://epfl.academia.edu/AlejandroArag&oacute;n}{my academic profile}

\end{document}
```

None of the resulting links take me to the right link in the browser, and actually the first two are disabled (they don't do anything).
Am I missing something?

**SOLUTION**

I just replaced it by the following line:

```
\href{http://epfl.academia.edu/AlejandroArag\%C3\%B3n}{my academic profile}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` before `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

If you run this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{http://epfl.academia.edu/AlejandroAragón}{my academic profile}

\href{http://epfl.academia.edu/AlejandroArag\'{o}n}{my academic profile}

\href{http://epfl.academia.edu/AlejandroArag&oacute;n}{my academic profile}

\end{document}
```

Your output will have link 1 and 2 working perfectly.  Link 3 seems broken.

Comment: No, that didn't work.

Comment: It's working for me here... I get to this page: http://epfl.academia.edu/AlejandroArag%F3n

Comment: It’s working for me as well, actually no matter if before or after `inputenc`. Is there a reason you specified the placement, @Mario?

Comment: @doncherry Yes :).  Take a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44699/27833

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon Are you still having a problem?  Did you run the code shown in the answer?

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me at all. Links 1 and 2 from the answer are broken for me. I'm compiling the document with pdflatex (using TeXShop).

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon are you creating a pdf output?  What viewer are you using?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating a pdf output. I'm using Preview for Mac.
I opened in Adobe Reader, and they work! So then this is a bug in Preview or something?

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon did you try what is said in this link? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65422/how-to-write-properly-an-accent-in-a-web-address