# Unicode characters in mailto address hyperref links

Tags: hyperref, unicode

I am trying to make names with special Danish characters in email addresses look right in the email the address in a `hyperref` link in the document compiled to PDF.
I have attempted:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{mailto:Ole-Bent Kjær <some.address@some.domain.dk>}{some.address}@some.domain.dk

\end{document}
```

I found and tried this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697003/865169 and this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111796/13780 to fix it, with no luck. The link in the resulting PDF file turns out `mailto:Ole-Bent Kj\T1\ae r <some.address@some.domain.dk>`. Is this a PDF problem that I cannot solve from LaTeX?

Comment: I don't think the issue here is `mailto:` as you see the same with `æ` (or `\ae`) in a standard link. I suspect that only some chars can be handled by the `unicode` option within hyperlinks (although the same char seems to be fine in the TOC bookmarks). I can't find any comment on the coverage in the docs, so I guess we need Heiko to answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *[`mailto:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto)* is a URI scheme, the rules for handling special characters are identical to those for URLs, which themselves also are URIs. Therefore one can use the so-called *[percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)*, which substitutes special characters by sequences of a percent sign followed by its UTF-8 byte sequence. For *æ*, this byte sequence is `C3 A6`, therefore its percent encoding would be `%C3%A6`. But as LaTeX takes the percent sign for the beginning of a comment, one has to escape it with a backslash, as well. After these steps, the result is the following:

```
\href{mailto:Ole-Bent Kj\%C3\%A6r <some.address@some.domain.dk>}{some.address}@some.domain.dk
```

Now, if the link is hovered over or clicked, the correct *æ* will show instead of `\%C3\%A6`.

See also here: [Hyperref: Scandinavian characters (æø) don't work in \url, hyperlink is wrong](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/hyperref-scandinavian-characters-%C3%A6%C3%B8-dont-work-in-url-hyperlink-is-wrong)

Comment: Actually it even works without escaping the percent signs, i. e., `Kj%C3%A6r` is also an option.

Comment: This sort of works for me; in my example, the link says "mailto:Ole-Bent Kj%C3%A6r <some.address@some.domain.dk>" when hovered in the PDF, but it does get translated to "æ" in the email client when clicked. Maybe this is an issue with the PDF viewer (evince)?

Comment: I only tried Adobe’s own reader, so you might be right about that.